# Как ограничить потребление ресурсов во время сборки проекта Qt?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Довольно большой проект, сборка съедает почти все ресурсы процессора, невозможно параллельно другими приложениями пользоваться.

Comment: Уменьшить количество потоков сборки.

Comment: @user207200 К сожалению в Qt Creator не могу найти поле, которое необходимо изменить.

Comment: В таком случае, вероятнее всего, по-умолчанию используется только 1 поток.

Comment: Какую систему сборки вы используете?

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=nice&category=1